# Dynamic Service Invokation - IOC

Tags: nestjs

how can I invoke a service's method dynamically (looked up from a hash-map) from a controller:

registration.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CacheService } from '../cache/cache.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../../config/logger/logger.service';

@Injectable()
export class RegistrationService {

  constructor(private readonly cache: CacheService,
    private readonly logger: LoggerService) {
  }

  async process() {
    this.logger.info(`RegistrationService - testThis - hit!`);
  }

}
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RegistrationService } from './modules/campaignOne/registration.service';

const SCREENS = {
  'start': 'this.registration.process'
};

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly registration: RegistrationService) {}

  @Get('test')
  async test(@Res() res: any): any {
    await eval(SCREENS['start'])();
    return Promise.resolve('ok');    
  }
}
```

When `await eval(SCREENS['start'])();` is executed, the method is called but an error is thrown at `this.logger..` because it can't resolve the logger.

The idea is to have multiple providers and logic in the controller will determine which provider to invoke dynamically.

I know the problem and solution lies in dependency injection and IOC - but I don't know how to resolve.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the factory approach with this.

First create an interface to define the shape of the "dynamic" service you want

```
//IService.ts

export interface IService {
    invoke(): Promise<void>;
}
```

Now all of your services that you want dynamic can implement this interface.
NOTE: This service is not using the nest @Injectable annotation because this class is not what will be actually injected as you'll see below.

```
//registration.service.ts

import { CacheService } from '../cache/cache.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../../config/logger/logger.service';

export class RegistrationService implements IService {

    private readonly cache: CacheService;
    private readonly logger: LoggerService;

    constructor(cache: CacheService, logger: LoggerService) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    async invoke() : Promise<void> {
        this.logger.info(`RegistrationService - testThis - hit!`);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

}
```

Now create your factory class that WILL be the thing that gets injected by the IOC

```
//ScreenFactory.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RegistrationService } from './modules/campaignOne/registration.service';

@Injectable()
export class ScreenFactory {

    private readonly cache: CacheService;
    private readonly logger: LoggerService;

    constructor(cache: CacheService, logger: LoggerService) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public getService(screenName: string) : IService {

        switch(screenName) {
            case 'start': return new RegistrationService(this.cache, this.logger);
            default: throw new Error('No service defined for the given screen');
        }

    }
}
```

Now in your module, inject the factory instead

```
import { Controller, Get, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScreenFactory } from './modules/ScreenFactory';

@Controller()
export class AppController {

    constructor(private readonly screenFactory: ScreenFactory) {}

    @Get('test')
    async test(@Res() res: any): any {

        //await eval(SCREENS['start'])();
        const service: IService = this.screenFactory.getService('start');
        await service.invoke();

        return Promise.resolve('ok');
    }
}
```

That's a lot of pseudo code but this is how I generally handle the "I need a different thing per request" type of scenario.